# Translate C# code to C++/cli code in VS2010

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I use windows 7 and VS2010. I have a C++/cli program to do some audio measurements and it worked well.

Now in the program  I want to add a function but I only have it's C# code.

I want to change this piece of C# code to C++/CLI so I could insert it in my C++/CLI program.

The c# code:

```
    //C#code:
ATc.LevelAndGain.Generator.On =  true;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
    IDynamicResultGraph^ graphResult = 
ATc.LevelAndGain.Graphs[resultName].Result;
    IMeterGraph GraphResult = graphResult.AsMeterGraph();
    ATc.ThdN.Generator.On = false;
```

The C++/CLI program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace ATCAPI;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Drawing::Imaging;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {   
    //Intialize ATC
    ATC^ ATc = gcnew ATC(false);
    //Make the application visible
    ATc ->Visible = true;
    String^ fileName = "AP_result_mic.doc";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);    

    //figure out where the application is running, because the sample 
   project will be copied to this directory
   String^ location = System::Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()- 
   >Location;
   String^ directory = System::IO::Path::GetDirectoryName(location);
   //tell ATc to load the project file
   ATc ->OpenProject(System::IO::Path::Combine(directory, "SPT.abprojx"));
   ATc ->ActiveMeasurement;
   String^ signalPathName = "MIC";
   String^ measurementName = "Level and Gain";
   String^ resultName = "Level";
   //tell ATc to show the specified measurement 
   ATc ->ShowMeasurement(signalPathName, measurementName);

   ......
```

Comment: The code has ^ to denote managed pointers so it looks like it’s already C++/CLI, not C#

Comment: Sorry, typo, I have updated it.

Comment: C++ has three different member access operators, `::`, `.`, and `->`.  Since we can't tell which type of member access is represented by `.` in C#, can't give you a conversion.  However you have the documentation, so you should be able to do it.